# R Data Structure equivalent of tuple + defaultdict in Python

Tags: python, r

I have a rows of the following format:

```
source1 dest1
source2 dest2
....
```

I want to count the occurrences of the combination of `source1`, `dest1`.  In Python I would do something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

count = defaultdict(int)

for row in file:
    source, dest = row.split
    count[(source, dest)] += 1
```

I can then sort my `count` dictionary by values to see the most common `source`, `dest` pair.  What is the best / most elegant way to do this in R?

Comment: A more pythonic solution would be to use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter); assuming that `source` and `dest` are hashable.

Comment: I don't speak Python. Thus, I have no idea what a "tuple + defaultdict" is.

Answer (score 0):

```
DF <- read.table(text="source1 dest1
source2 dest2")

table(DF)
#          V2
# V1        dest1 dest2
#   source1     1     0
#   source2     0     1

as.data.frame(table(DF))
#       V1    V2 Freq
#1 source1 dest1    1
#2 source2 dest1    0
#3 source1 dest2    0
#4 source2 dest2    1
```